# How to draw a circle around a SVG and fill

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="50px" height="50px" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="7 7 50 50">
<path id="p" d="M43.5,29.7h-2.6c0.2,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.3,2.3 c0,5.1-4.1,9.2-9.2,9.2c-5.1,0-9.2-4.1-9.2-9.2c0-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.3-2.3h-2.6v12.7c0,0.6,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2h20.8c0.6,0,1.2-0.5,1.2-1.2 V29.7z M43.5,21.6c0-0.6-0.5-1.2-1.2-1.2h-3.5c-0.6,0-1.2,0.5-1.2,1.2v3.5c0,0.6,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2h3.5c0.6,0,1.2-0.5,1.2-1.2V21.6z  M32,26.2c-3.2,0-5.8,2.6-5.8,5.8c0,3.2,2.6,5.8,5.8,5.8s5.8-2.6,5.8-5.8C37.8,28.8,35.2,26.2,32,26.2 M43.5,47H20.5 c-1.9,0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5V20.5c0-1.9,1.5-3.5,3.5-3.5h23.1c1.9,0,3.5,1.5,3.5,3.5v23.1C47,45.4,45.5,47,43.5,47" fill="#3f729b"/>
</svg>
```

It renders the following:

[image]

I want this to be contained in a circle like this:

[image]

How would I achieve this?

Comment: `transform: rotate(360deg)` seems... questionable.

Comment: Anyway. Just draw a blue circle and then draw your path on top of it replacing its fill with white.

Comment: The easiest way is to change the viewBox to `viewBox="7 7 50 50"` Next you add a background and rounded corners to the svg: `svg{background:#3f729b; border-radius:50%}` and change the fill of the path to white

Comment: @enxaneta thanks! Where does `7` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the bounding box of the icon, in this case thePath:

```
let bb = thePath.getBBox();
```

Knowing the bounding box you can change a "tight" `viewBox = "17 17 30 30"`

```js
//this is returning the bounding box of the path
let bb = thePath.getBBox();
/*{
  "x": 17,
  "y": 17,
  "width": 30.099998474121094,
  "height": 30
}*/

//Knowing the bounding box you can change a "tight" viewBox = "17 17 30 30"


console.log(`${bb.x} ${bb.y} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}`);
document.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("viewBox",`${bb.x} ${bb.y} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}`)
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="50px" height="50px" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
<path id="thePath" d="M43.5,29.7h-2.6c0.2,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.3,2.3 c0,5.1-4.1,9.2-9.2,9.2c-5.1,0-9.2-4.1-9.2-9.2c0-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.3-2.3h-2.6v12.7c0,0.6,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2h20.8c0.6,0,1.2-0.5,1.2-1.2 V29.7z M43.5,21.6c0-0.6-0.5-1.2-1.2-1.2h-3.5c-0.6,0-1.2,0.5-1.2,1.2v3.5c0,0.6,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2h3.5c0.6,0,1.2-0.5,1.2-1.2V21.6z  M32,26.2c-3.2,0-5.8,2.6-5.8,5.8c0,3.2,2.6,5.8,5.8,5.8s5.8-2.6,5.8-5.8C37.8,28.8,35.2,26.2,32,26.2 M43.5,47H20.5 c-1.9,0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5V20.5c0-1.9,1.5-3.5,3.5-3.5h23.1c1.9,0,3.5,1.5,3.5,3.5v23.1C47,45.4,45.5,47,43.5,47" fill="#3f729b"/>
</svg>
```

If you need some sort of padding around the image you can do this:

```js
//this is returning the bounding box of the path
let bb = thePath.getBBox();
/*{
  "x": 17,
  "y": 17,
  "width": 30.099998474121094,
  "height": 30
}*/

//if you need some sort of padding around the icon you can do this:

let padding = 10;


document.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("viewBox",`${bb.x - padding} ${bb.y - padding} ${bb.width + 2*padding} ${bb.height + 2*padding}`)
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="50px" height="50px" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
<path id="thePath" d="M43.5,29.7h-2.6c0.2,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.3,2.3 c0,5.1-4.1,9.2-9.2,9.2c-5.1,0-9.2-4.1-9.2-9.2c0-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.3-2.3h-2.6v12.7c0,0.6,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2h20.8c0.6,0,1.2-0.5,1.2-1.2 V29.7z M43.5,21.6c0-0.6-0.5-1.2-1.2-1.2h-3.5c-0.6,0-1.2,0.5-1.2,1.2v3.5c0,0.6,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2h3.5c0.6,0,1.2-0.5,1.2-1.2V21.6z  M32,26.2c-3.2,0-5.8,2.6-5.8,5.8c0,3.2,2.6,5.8,5.8,5.8s5.8-2.6,5.8-5.8C37.8,28.8,35.2,26.2,32,26.2 M43.5,47H20.5 c-1.9,0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5V20.5c0-1.9,1.5-3.5,3.5-3.5h23.1c1.9,0,3.5,1.5,3.5,3.5v23.1C47,45.4,45.5,47,43.5,47" fill="#3f729b"/>
</svg>
```

Next - as I've commented -  you add a background and rounded corners to the svg: svg{background:#3f729b; border-radius:50%} and change the fill of the path to white

Answer (score 1):

Set the SVG color to white. The `background-color` to blue and give it a `border-radius` of 50%.